# FileConnection on Storm 9550

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-storm, connector

I'm using the following code to create a file and write data into it:

```
fileName = "file:///store/home/user/myapp/groups.xml";    

try {
  fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fileName, Connector.READ_WRITE);
  if (!fc.exists())
    fc.create();                
    os = fc.openDataOutputStream();
    String XMLString = "blablabla";
    byte[] FinalXML = XMLString.getBytes();
    os.write(FinalXML);
    os.close();
    fc.close();        
} catch (IOException e) {
  Dialog.alert(e.getMessage());
}
```

It works good on my bb 9700 with OS6 and on 9700 simulator. But it doesn't work on 9550 device and simulator. I'm getting IOException. The message says

> File not found

Does anybody have some voodoo magic that will help me?

Comment: Have you checked that the file name makes sense on both devices? Sometimes the directory structure is different if there is or isn't a media card inserted. You can see what directories there are via Media -> Menu -> Browse or something similar in the device.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add fileName that contains path. Fixed. I'm trying to save file on the device memory. I think that this part of path file:///store/home/user/ is the same for all BB devices. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the folder "file:///store/home/user/myapp/" does not exist yet. Just check for its presence first, if not present - create and then go on with rest of your code.

BTW, the "file:///store/home/user/" path is valid for all mentioned devices.

Comment: Ok, i've tried and was able to write file here "file:///store/home/user/" using storm simulator. But strange, that 9700 can create a folder by itself, when i use this command "fc.create", but 9550 - cannot. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

IOExeption go if the firewall disallows a connection that is not btspp or comm. so you have to add permission for your program such as FILE_API ..... you can read book : Advance BB dev to do this